# What is this strange error: Tuple type element list cannot be empty

Tags: spfx, error, sharepoint-on-prem, react, 2019

Environment: SP2019 onprem

SPFx version: 1.4.1

All of sudden below error is coming while doing `gulp build` or `gulp serve`.

> A tuple type element list cannot be empty.Error - typescript - src/webparts/displayStateInformation/components/DisplayStateInformation.tsx(14,4): error TS1122: A tuple type element list cannot be empty.

How to resolve this?

Below is my interface

```
export interface IItemsData {
  k:[];
}
```

Error throwing for property `k`

Comment: Can you please add the code in `DisplayStateInformation.tsx` file to your question?

Comment: i have added the interface where it is throwing error

Comment: What are you storing in array? Strings?Numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing it as an array of string then try using below code:

```
export interface IItemsData {
   k: string[];
}
```

Comment: Yeah correct. but strange thing is this code is working in another machine without any error. If i clone the repository and do the build it is throwing error. Really hard to adjust with this node and npm :)